# C- an ADT that keeps crashing

Tags: c, adt

I'm trying to create an ADT , 
first of all, here is the basic information about it:

```
typedef struct orange_t* Orange;

typedef enum {
JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC,
} Month;

struct orange_t {

short size;
Month expirationMonth;
char** foodCompanies;
int maxNumberOfFoodCompanies;
int sellingPrice;
};
```

now im trying to create a function that will "create" new orange like that:

```
Orange orangeCreate(short size,Month expirationMonth
    ,int maxNumberOfFoodCompanies,int sellingPrice)
 {
   Orange new_orange=(Orange)malloc(sizeof(struct orange_t));
   if(new_orange==NULL)
   {
        return NULL;
    }
   if((sellingPrice<0)||(size>256||size<1)||(maxNumberOfFoodCompanies<0)||(expirationMonth>12)
        ||(expirationMonth<1))
        {
        return NULL;
        }
new_orange->sellingPrice=sellingPrice;
new_orange->maxNumberOfFoodCompanies=maxNumberOfFoodCompanies;
new_orange->expirationMonth=expirationMonth;
new_orange->size=size;
for(int i=0;i<new_orange->maxNumberOfFoodCompanies;i++)
{
    new_orange->foodCompanies[i]=NULL;
}
return new_orange;
}
```

when I tried to check the function with the simple `main()`:

```
int main()
{
Orange orange=orangeCreate(3,JAN,10,4);
printf("the size is %d\n",orange->size);
orangeDestroy(orange);
return 0;
}
```

the program keeps crashing, I guess I didn't change the values in orange as I should, and they might still be `NULL`.
where did I go wrong here?

Comment: You are not allocating `foodCompanies` anywhere, but trying to index and assign it.

Comment: in C, the returned value from `malloc()` and family of functions is type `void *`, which can be assigned to any other pointer.   Casting the return type is completely unnecessary and leads to difficulties when debugging and or maintaining the code.   The typedef name `Orange` is misleading as it is actually a pointer type.   Much better to typedef is as just `struct orange_t` with no pointer, then add the '*' as necessary in the body of the code.

Comment: an enum starts with 0 (unless specifically defined otherwise) so the check for the `expirationMonth` is not correct, unless the enum is modified so the first entry is: `JAN=1,`

Answer (score 1):

`JAN` is 0. if `expirationMonth<1` you are returning `NULL` from `orangeCreate`.

Also: you are not checking the return value of `orangeCreate`. And you are leaking memory in `orangeCreate` when you are just returning `NULL` without `free`ing the allocated `new_orange`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not allocating memory for `char** foodCompanies;`

---

While allocating memory here

```
Orange new_orange=malloc(sizeof(struct orange_t));
```

You have allocated space for the pointer variable `char** foodCompanies;`, but have not allocated space where it would point to.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate some memory and store the address of it to `new_orange->foodCompanies` before accessing it.

Possible fix:

```
Orange orangeCreate(short size,Month expirationMonth
    ,int maxNumberOfFoodCompanies,int sellingPrice)
 {
   Orange new_orange=malloc(sizeof(struct orange_t));
   if(new_orange==NULL)
   {
        return NULL;
    }
   if((sellingPrice<0)||(size>256||size<1)||(maxNumberOfFoodCompanies<0)||(expirationMonth>12)
        ||(expirationMonth<1))
        {
        return NULL;
        }
new_orange->sellingPrice=sellingPrice;
new_orange->maxNumberOfFoodCompanies=maxNumberOfFoodCompanies;
new_orange->expirationMonth=expirationMonth;
new_orange->size=size;
new_orange->foodCompanies=malloc(sizeof(char*)*new_orange->maxNumberOfFoodCompanies); /* add this line */
for(int i=0;i<new_orange->maxNumberOfFoodCompanies;i++)
{
    new_orange->foodCompanies[i]=NULL;
}
return new_orange;
}
```

Note: it is discouraged to cast the result of `malloc()` in C.
[c - Do I cast the result of malloc? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)